# How to clone Ubuntu from HDD to SSD using Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, 20.10, clone

I have dual boot windows and Ubuntu 20.10 on HDD. I have installed a SSD in place of DVD player on HP laptop.
I want to know if there is any way I can clone Ubuntu to a partition of new SSD using the Windows.
I have tried using Minitoos which detects the windows OS and clones it to SSD but I want to clone Ubuntu.

Comment: "using the Windows" ask a windows user :) We are not expected to know how to do that using Windows The contents of what you clone does not matter. Besides that: I consider it a bad idea: reinstalling on the ssd is the better method.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do it rennin Ubuntu in VirtualBox in Windows. Best to do it from Ubuntu on a Live USB.

Comment: This user cloned his HDD to new SSD and has massive issues of duplicate UUIDs & GUIDs. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2455446  Note with UEFI and gpt partitioning, it is not as easy to copy a partition as GUID is unique to partition and must match primary partition table & backup partition table. Good time to test that your backups are complete, as new install & restore from backup will show it has everything. But you still have old install, just in case. When hard drive fails & you have to restore from backup, you to not have old install to go back to.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your SSD is same size as the HDD, use [clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/), then remove the Windows partition once you boot from SSD, expand Ubuntu to use the storage that was made available when removing Windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

By cloning your're trying the hardest way. I'm not sure if that's needed. You may backup /home and do fresh installation to SSD. Copy the backup to new /home.

Or you still want to do the hardest way by cloning? You may use [CloneZilla](https://clonezilla.org/)

Personally, I don't see a reason why we should take the hardest way. If you have some specific reasons, let us know in comments.

Comment: I've tried fresh install on new SSD. but it's showing boot device failed error message. I've tried boot repair, turned off secure boot and enabled legacy boot but no luck. I have a working Ubuntu boot on old HDD so I thought maybe if I clone this it might work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple disc cloning software but wasn't able to boot from external SSD. When I replaced the Original HDD with new SSD, I was able to boot from it. Maybe there was some problem with the SSD connection to laptop suing the CD drive.